# Codeigniter .htaccess not getting write

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my .htaccess , but i am not getting the links correct

whenever i click on a link which doesn't have index.php it redirects to the wamp server homepage

Comment: you'll have to explain what your problem is better than that. What IS happening? What isn't happening that you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assumming that **index.php** is your index page.

and change in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```